How can I center my LaTeX text block in double sides printing?
I need to print double sided a5 from a translation of a book in LaTeX. Just bought an HP LAserjet 209 only to find out it does not do a5 D-S. So I need to print a5 block on a4 paper and therefore need it centered left and right.
I have been using TexShop freeware:
\documentclass{10pt,a5paper,article}{memoir}

and trying things like
\isopage
\semiisopage
\setlrmarginsandblock{.8in}{.8in}{*}

etc...
but have not so far been able to center my text.

Wouldn't it be better to place two A5 pages side by side onto A4 only for printing? → pdfjam or a5toa4 of package pfarrei.

But maybe you are searching for package crop. Sorry, but for me your question is not really clear. For example I do not understand, why you need centering.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For me the question is rather clear: the goal is double-sided printing, therefore each side needs to be at the center of the page (to allow cutting the sides and bottom with a paper cutter, or if you leave it as A4 then the pages are still symmetric). What is unclear though is the setup of the document, just a documentclass and some isolated commands are not really sufficient to provide an appropriate answer.

@Marijn But in this case you need to cut all four edges to get A5. If you'd place the A5 page at the top of the A4 sheet instead of vertically centered, you would need to cut only 3 edges. And if you would put the odd A5 pages onto the top left and the even pages onto the top right, you would need to cut only two edges. And if you'd arrange two A5 pages on each side of the A4 page, you would need only a single cut in the middle. So IMHO centering is not really needed and not even always the best solution. But if you want it, see my second comment. But maybe there are untold facts.

@cabohah if you want to reproduce a double-sided printed A5 document on A4 then you need to (horizontally) center the pages, because only then the contents on the front of the paper and the contents on the back of the paper are in the same position on the sheet of paper. The question mentioned to center left and right, in my comment I didn't specify that but since it is in the question I also intended horizontal centering only, so the contents at the top. In any case that doesn't make a big difference, if you also center vertically then you need to cut more paper but the idea is the same.

@Marijn As I've already told: If odd pages are aligned left and even pages aligned right, they are also on the same position and can be cut. Centering is not the only possibility. But as also already told, if you want centering → package crop (and yes, option center does horizontal an vertical centering, you can just define another height to have horizontal centering without effective vertical centering).

@Marijn Moreover from the answer it seems, that the text block should be centered not the a5 block. IMHO this is not recommended for double side printing, so seems to be strange. So for me the question is still unclear. Sorry.

Thanks for all the comments. Sorry if my question was too terse.
I have almost cracked it by using
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,article]{memoir}
 \usepackage[a4paper,
             top=7cm, bottom=7cm, 
             left = 5.3cm, right=5.3cm]{geometry}

It is perfect horizontally but half a line out vertically now. But according to other blogs this is just because my printer doesn't do the grabbing back perfectly. But it will be good enough for me anyway. So thanks for replying!
